# Why does page content not change with Swup Transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swup

I am trying just a simple project in which the pages have a transition using Swup (https://swup.js.org/getting-started/example), but I can't get it working.

If I click on the Link the URL is changing, but the Content stays the same, from subpage.html I can change to index.html, but there are no transitions in all cases.

```
<a href="/subpage.html">Other Page</a>
```

[Right URL but wrong Content][1]

---

This is all the HTML, CSS & JS:

```
<body>

  <style>
    .transition-fade{
      transition: 0.5s;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .html.is-animating .transition-fade{
      opacity: 0;
    }
  </style>
  
  <div class="container">

    <main id="swup" class="transition-fade">
      <h1>homepage</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <a href="/subpage.html">Other Page</a>
    </main>
  </div>

  <script src="/node_modules/swup/dist/swup.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    const swup = new Swup();
  </script>

</body>
```

---

And this is the HTML on subpage.html:

```
<body>

  <style>
    .transition-fade{
      transition: 0.5s;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .html.is-animating .transition-fade{
      opacity: 0;
    }
  </style>
  
  <div class="container">
    <main id="swup" class="transition-fade">
      <h1>Supage</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <a href="/index.html">Homepage</a>
    </main>
  </div>

</body>
```

Please help me, what am I doing wrong? 
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbq3E.png

Comment: If it is too complicated, maybe you can name alternatives to Swup?

Answer (score 0):

You need the 2 scripts on every page that you want to have transitioned:

```
  <script src="/node_modules/swup/dist/swup.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    const swup = new Swup();
  </script>
```